# Problem with parameter of fetch() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, react-redux

I created small application using ASP.NET 6.0 and React+Redux.
I created Controller with name "ToursController" and use `` fetch(`tours`) `` inside Tours.ts store to fetch data from ToursController. But Tours.ts converted into Tours.js with `fetch("tour")`. So I have 404 Not found.
Why `` fetch(`tours`) `` in TypeScript converted into `fetch("tour")`? And how can I get away it?

Comment: Please add the code that triggers the error, it is impossible to help you without seeing the code.

Comment: "*Why ``fetch(`tours`)`` in TypeScript converted into `fetch("tour")`?*" because it's the same. A template literal with no dynamic parts is equivalent to a string literal. It's not clear why you consider this is a problem, however

Answer (score 0):

It's magic, but I changed `` fetch(`tours`) `` to `fetch('tours')` in the TypeScript code and all work fine.

Comment: Your formatting was ambiguous. I’ve edited your answer to provide more defined formatting. Can you please review and confirm that this is what you intended?